# Retrieve jqXHR in jquery file upload plugin's fileuploadsend event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using drag-drop to trigger my upload, so I'm not able to simply capture the return from findupload('send') to get the jqXHR.

So in the 'fileuploadsend' event I'm trying to grab the jqXHR element from the data object, however data.jqXHR seems to be undefined?

```
    $('#fileupload')
        .fileupload({
           ...
        }).bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(data.jqXHR)
        });
```

The output for the data object show's a jqXHR element exists and is an object like so:

```
jqXHR: Object
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseText: "[{"url": "/media/pictures/392_frm_20130412081933_d3fee37c7a654dfca066ca3fa389b491.jpg", "filename": "waves_1600.jpeg", "sortDate": null, "albumId": 67, "published": false, "source_id": "pfi392", "thumbnailUrl": "/media/cache/a1/c1/a1c1d4f74614cf041b29e315a1f9a08a.jpg", "id": 499}]"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

However for whatever reason the console.log(data.jqXHR) simply gives undefined.

If I run `for (k in data) { console.log(k) }` then jqXHR is nowhere to be seen in the listed:

```
disabled
create
dropZone
pasteZone
replaceFileInput
singleFileUploads
sequentialUploads
forceIframeTransport
multipart
recalculateProgress
progressInterval
bitrateInterval
formData
add
processData
contentType
cache
url
dataType
fileInput
files
originalFiles
paramName
submit
form
type
formAcceptCharset
uploadedBytes
headers
data
blob
xhr
_bitrateTimer
```

Comment: Sorry not sure I ever did :(

Comment: I notice there is a data.xhr - is this what you are after?

Comment: hi. i have the exact issue over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198306/blueimp-fileupload-fileuploadsubmit-error-in-returning-responsetext  did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used basic plus UI version of jquery-fileupload.

First, paste part of jquery.fileupload.ui.js in my javascript
fileupload source. and modified some part.

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/common/fileupload',

    // pasted this part, If the file transfer successful
    // 파일 전송에 성공하면
    done: function (e, data) {
        if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            return false;
        }
        var that = $(this).data('blueimp-fileupload') ||
                $(this).data('fileupload'),
            getFilesFromResponse = data.getFilesFromResponse ||
                that.options.getFilesFromResponse,
            files = getFilesFromResponse(data),
            template,
            deferred;
        if (data.context) {
            data.context.each(function (index) {
                var file = files[index] ||
                        {error: 'Empty file upload result'};
                deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
                that._transition($(this)).done(
                    function () {
                        var node = $(this);
                        template = that._renderDownload([file])
                            .replaceAll(node);
                        that._forceReflow(template);
                        that._transition(template).done(
                            function () {
                                data.context = $(this);
                                that._trigger('completed', e, data);
                                that._trigger('finished', e, data);
                                deferred.resolve();


                                // It succeeded in using jqXHR, I was need of file auto increment id,
                                console.log("fileuploadsuccess", data.jqXHR.responseJSON.files_info[0]);
                                // and I called custom callback function.
                                fn_file_callback("fileuploadsuccess", e, data.jqXHR.responseJSON.files_info[0]);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            });
        } else {
            template = that._renderDownload(files)[
                that.options.prependFiles ? 'prependTo' : 'appendTo'
            ](that.options.filesContainer);
            that._forceReflow(template);
            deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
            that._transition(template).done(
                function () {
                    data.context = $(this);
                    that._trigger('completed', e, data);
                    that._trigger('finished', e, data);
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            );
        }
    },

    // then pasted this part.. If the file remove done.
    // 파일을 삭제하면
    destroy: function (e, data) {
        if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            return false;
        }
        var that = $(this).data('blueimp-fileupload') ||
                $(this).data('fileupload'),
            removeNode = function () {
                that._transition(data.context).done(
                    function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                        that._trigger('destroyed', e, data);

                        // add here, I called custom callback function about file deletion.
                        fn_file_callback("filedeletesuccess", e, data.url.replace("/common/deleteFile/", ""));
                    }
                );
            };
        if (data.url) {
            data.dataType = data.dataType || that.options.dataType;
            $.ajax(data).done(removeNode).fail(function () {
                that._trigger('destroyfailed', e, data);
            });
        } else {
            removeNode();
        }
    }
});
```

> From here the rest.

```
// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);

if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost:8080') {
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '/common/fileupload',
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    });
    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/common/fileupload',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
    }
} else {
    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
}
```

good luck to you!